# tmux - interactive window selector fullscreen while in split

Tags: tmux

If i open the window selector with `<prefix>w` while in a split, the window selector shows only in the current split. How can i make the window selector fill the entire terminal?

The solution ideally should be seamless: i.e., should open the window selector fullscreen regardless of whether we are already zoomed, and when leaving the window selector, the zoom state should be the same as before the window selector was opened.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907866/fullscreen-tmux-sessions-selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version of tmux (3.2a), the window selector starts zoomed by default for me.
You can also add a custom keybinding that adds the `-Z` flag to explicitly request a zoomed selector:

```
bind -n M-w choose-window -Z
```

This doesn't interfere with the current zoom state of your panes.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me! The `-Z` option also works with `choose-tree`: I am using `bind s choose-tree -s -G -Z` now

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:** Zoom the pane with `<prefix>z` or `resize-pane -Z`.

---

The default function for `<prefix>w` is `choose-tree -w` (version 2.6+; in older versions it was `choose-window`).  These are displayed in the `pane`, so zoom the pane to fill the window temporarily.

Combining the two operations on a single keybind should be fairly straightforward.  This can go in your `.tmux.conf` or into a running session (`<prefix>:`):

```
# replace default window-chooser: zoom first
bind-key -T prefix w resize-pane -Z \; choose-tree -w
```

See [`man tmux`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#choose-tree):

```
choose-tree [-GNsw] [-F format] [-f filter]
            [-O sort-order] [-t target-pane] [template]
    Put a pane into tree mode, where a session, window or pane may 
    be chosen interactively from a list. -s starts with sessions 
    collapsed and -w with windows collapsed. [...]
```

Comment: A few problems with this: If I am already zoomed, it will unzoom. Second problem is, when I leave the choose-tree i will have to manually unzoom.

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy zooming is the mechanism that answers the question you asked.  you're always welcome to edit this or post your own answer if you come up with a `bind-key` command or other automation method that suits your workflow better.  personally, i don't know any way to query the zoom state of the window, so i have no additional suggestions.